# Not able to read config file in Angular2

Tags: angular, configuration-files

Below is my code where I am trying to read the values from the JSON config file. But when I call the method `getApiURL` it returns an empty string. Not able to understand whats going wrong here...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebApiConfiguration {
    public apiURL: string = "";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }
    public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._http.get('/Utils/LSConfig.json')  
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    this.apiURL = data.WebAPIUrl;
                    resolve(true);
                },
                err => console.log(err)
                );
        });
    }


    public getApiURL = (): string => {
        return this.apiURL;
    }
}
```

This config class is passed as injectable to calling constructor class like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class LSService implements ILSService {

    private actionUrl: string;
    private headers: Headers;

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _configuration: WebApiConfiguration      ) {
        this.actionUrl = _configuration.getApiURL();
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
```

My config `LSConfig.json` file is simple like below and contains just one value:

```
{
  "WebAPIUrl": "http://localhost/WebAPI/"
}
```

Now, every time, `_configuration.getApiURL()` returns an empty string. Not sure whats going wrong... any idea?

Comment: '/Utils/LSConfig.json' make sure http api find this first, than console.log(data.WebAPIUrl) with in load().

Comment: Did you got the solutions for this problem? I am also in the same situation where I need to implement the same kind of functionality. only difference in mine is it can have many config entries. any inputs?